# appending list in python if with item from another list

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [('a', '1'),('b', '2'),('c', '3')
list2 = [('a', 'x'),('b', 'y'),('c', 'z')
```

I want to create:

```
list3 = [('a', '1', 'x'),('b', '2', 'y'),('c', '3', 'z')
```

I've tried .append, with no success:

```
list3 = list1.append(list2[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `list comprehension`:

```
list1 = [('a', '1'),('b', '2'),('c', '3')]
list2 = [('a', 'x'),('b', 'y'),('c', 'z')]
list3= [(list1[i][0],list1[i][1],list2[i][1]) for i in range(len(list1))]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[('a', '1', 'x'), ('b', '2', 'y'), ('c', '3', 'z')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
list1 = [('a', '1'),('b', '2'),('c', '3')]
list2 = [('a', 'x'),('b', 'y'),('c', 'z')]
new_result = [(a, c, d) for (a, c), (_, d) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Output:

```
[('a', '1', 'x'), ('b', '2', 'y'), ('c', '3', 'z')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union`.

```
list1 = [('a', '1'),('b', '2'),('c', '3')]
list2 = [('a', 'x'),('b', 'y'),('c', 'z')]

list3 = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
  for j in range(len(list2)):
    if(i == j):
      list3.append(set(list1[i]) | set(list2[j]))
      break;
```

Output:

```
[{'a', 'x', '1'}, {'y', '2', 'b'}, {'3', 'c', 'z'}]
```